# Tidy up Liquibase scripts

Tags: java, spring, backend, liquibase

I have a lot of already applied liquibase scripts in one single `changelogs` directory. The problem is that the directory has got too big. So i'd like to create a bunch of subdirectories in vein like `changelogs/2014`, `changelogs/2015`, ...

But obviously whenever i move the scripts to a different directory, Liquibase fails on trying to reapply the scripts. Is there any workaround i could utilize?

i tried to `<includeAll path="changelogs/2014" />` and `<include file="changelogs/2014/changelog-2014.xml" />`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your changeSets were executed, you can do the following:

1. Rearrange changelogs in subdirectories.
2. Run [changelog-sync](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/change-tracking/changelog-sync.html) command.

After you rearrange the paths of the changelogs, Liquibase will treat them as new changelogs. And will attempt to execute them.

To prevent it, you can run

```
liquibase changelog-sync --changelog-file=example-changelog.xml
```

to mark all the changeSets as executed.

---

Or you can do the following:

1. Rearrange changelogs in subdirectories.
2. Add [logicalFilePath](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/logicalfilepath.html) attribute to override file name and path of the changeLog files.

Setting the "old" logicalFilePath should make Liquibase think that file path has not been changed.

> The logicalFilePath attribute is used to override the file name and
> path when creating the unique identifier of changesets. The
> logicalFilePath attribute is required when moving or renaming
> changelogs to prevent Liquibase from redeploying the corresponding
> changesets as their unique identifier will have been changed by the
> move.
>
> You can specify the logicalFilePath attribute in the root section of
> the  in your changelog or in a specific changeset.

E.g.:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    <!-- schema info -->
    logicalFilePath="../com/example/baseChangelog.xml">
<changeSet id="1" author="your.name"> 
....
<changeSet id="2" author="your.name"> 
....
</databaseChangeLog>
```